# Empty angle-brackets after a function's name in explicit specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Here is a code from the article [Why not specialize function templates?](http://gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

```
template<class T>
void f(T);                     // (1)
template<class T>
void f(T*);                   // (2)
template<>
void f<>(int*);             // (3)
```

My question is about the last declaration. What does that syntax mean? When we want to fully specialize a function template, e.g. (1), for some type we usually write:

```
template<>
void f<int>(int);
```

i.e. we put that type into the angle-brackets after the function' name.

So what does the syntax (3) means?

Answer (score 6):

In your case,

```
template<> void f<>(int*);
```

is an explicit specialization of

```
template<class T> void f(T*);
```

base template. It's the same as

```
template<> void f<int>(int*);
```

just the template argument is deduced.

---

You can even write:

```
template<> void f(int*);
```

with the same effect. A similar case is presented on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), see section **Explicit specializations of function templates**, where there is written:

> When specializing a function template, its template arguments can be omitted if template argument deduction can provide them from the function arguments.

The relevant part of the C++ Standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#11.

Answer (score 2):

A missing template argument will be deduced by the compiler if you don't provide it. In this particular case it will be deduced to `int*` because the second template is more specialized (but both are the candidates). So

```
template<> void f<>(int*)
```

will become

```
template<> void f<int>(int*)
```

after type deduction.